# Why does response time go up when the number of concurrent requests per second to my Asp.Net Core API goes up

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm testing an endpoint under load. For 1 request per second, the average response time is around 200ms. The endpoint does a few DB lookups (all read) that are pretty fast and it's async throughout.

However when doing a few hundred requests per second (req/sec), the average response time goes up to over a second.

I've had a look at the best practices guide at:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Some suggestions like "*Avoid blocking calls*" and "*Minimize large object allocations*" seem like they don't apply since I'm already using async throughout and my response size for a single request is less than 50 KB.

There are a couple though that seem like they **might be useful**, for example:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#high-performance
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-2.2#pool-http-connections-with-httpclientfactory

**Questions:**

1. Why would the average response time go up with an increased req/sec?
2. Are the suggestions above that I've marked as being 'might be useful' likely to help? I ask because while I would like to try out all, I have limited time available to me unfortunately, so I'd like to try out options that are most likely to help first.
3. Are there any other options worth considering?

I've had a look at these two existing threads, but neither answer my question:

> [Correlation between requests per second and response time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701537)
>
> [ASP.NET Web API - Handle more requests per second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37022458)

Comment: If all the database queries are fast, why does it take 200ms to respond under low load?  How fast are they? Unless your response time is dominated by network latency, you would expect it to take longer to do more work.  How is your connection pooler to do the database set up?

Comment: @jjanes I suspect network latency is involved in the response time. On localhost, the endpoint responds in under 20ms. But what is fast though? Even if the actual endpoint does take 200ms, surely with concurrency, it should not make that response time go up by a factor of 5 with increased req/sec should it? Maybe I’m mistaken but isn’t that the whole point of concurrency?

Comment: I’m not sure about the connection pooler, I’ll need to get back to you on that.

Answer (score 4):

It will be hard to answer your specific issue without access to the code but the main things to consider is the size and complexity of the database queries being generated by EF. Using async/await will increase the responsiveness of your web server to start requests, but the request handling time under load will depend largely on the queries being run as the database becomes the contention point.  You will want to ensure that all queries are as minimalist as possible.  For example, there is a huge difference between the following 3 statements:

```
var someData = context.SomeTable.Include(x => x.SomeOtherTable)
    .ToList()
    .Where(x => x.SomeCriteriaMethod())
    .ToList();

var someData = context.SomeTable.Include(x => x.SomeOtherTable)
    .Where(x => x.SomeField == someField && x.SomeOtherTable.SomeOtherField == someOtherField)
    .ToList();

var someData = context.SomeTable
    .Where(x => x.SomeField == someField && x.SomeOtherTable.SomeOtherField == someOtherField)
    .Select(x => new SomeViewModel 
    {
       SomeTableId = x.SomeTableId,
       SomeField = x.SomeField,
       SomeOtherField = x.SomeOtherTable.SomeOtherField
    }).ToList();
```

Examples like the first above are extremely inefficient as they end up loading all data from the related tables from the database before filtering rows. Even though your web server may only pass back a few rows, it has requested everything from the database. These kinds of scenarios creep into apps when developers face scenarios where they want to filter on a value that EF cannot translate to SQL (such as a Function) so they solve it by putting a `ToList` call, or it can be introduced as a byproduct of poor separation such as a repository pattern that returns an IEnumerable.

The second example is a little better where they avoid using the read-all ToList() call, but the calls are still loading back entire rows for data that isn't necessary. This ties up resources on the database and web servers.

The third example demonstrates refining queries to just return the absolute minimum of data that the consumer needs. This can make better use of indexes and execution plans on the database server.

Other performance pitfalls that you can face under load are things like lazy loads. Databases will execute a finite number of concurrent requests, so if it turns out some queries are kicking off additional lazy load requests, when there is no load, these are executed immediately. Under load though, they are queued up along with other queries and lazy load requests which can tie down data pulls.

Ultimately you should run an SQL profiler against your database to capture the kinds and numbers of SQL queries being executed. When executing in a test environment, pay close attention to the Read count and CPU cost rather than the total execution time. As a general rule of thumb higher read and CPU cost queries will be far more susceptible to execution time blow-out under load. They require more resources to run, and "touch" more rows meaning more waiting for row/table locks.

Another thing to watch out for are "heavy" queries in very large data systems that will need to touch a lot of rows, such as reports, and in some cases, highly customizable search queries. If these should be needed, you should consider planning your database design to include a read-only replica to run reports or large search expressions against to avoid row lock scenarios in your primary database that can degrade responsiveness for the typical read and write queries.

Edit: Identifying lazy load queries.

These show up in a profiler where you query against a top level table, but then see a number of additional queries for related tables following it.

For example, say you have a table called Order, with a related table called Product, another called Customer and another called Address for a delivery address.  To read all orders for a date range you'd expect to see a query such as:

```
SELECT [OrderId], [Quantity], [OrderDate] [ProductId], [CustomerId], [DeliveryAddressId] FROM [dbo].[Orders] WHERE [OrderDate] >= '2019-01-01' AND [OrderDate] < '2020-01-01'
```

Where you just wanted to load Orders and return them.

When the serializer iterates over the fields, it finds a Product, Customer, and Address referenced, and by attempting to read those fields, will trip lazy loading resulting in:

```
SELECT [CustomerId], [Name] FROM [dbo].[Customers] WHERE [CustomerId] = 22
SELECT [ProductId], [Name], [Price] FROM [dbo].[Products] WHERE [ProductId] = 1023
SELECT [AddressId], [StreetNumber], [City], [State], [PostCode] FROM [dbo].[Addresses] WHERE [AddressId] = 1211
```

If your original query returned 100 Orders, you would see potentially 100x the above set of queries, one set for each order as a lazy load hit on 1 order row would attempt to look up a related customer by customer ID, a related product by Product ID, and a related Address by Delivery Address ID. This can, and does get costly. It may not be visible when run on a test environment, but that adds up to a lot of potential queries.

If eager loaded using `.Include()` for the related entities, EF will compose `JOIN` statements to get the related rows all in one hit which is considerably faster than fetching each individual related entity. Still, that can result in pulling a lot of data you don't need. The best way to avoid this extra cost is to leverage projection through `Select` to retrieve just the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Steve, appreciate it. Apologies for not showing the actual code, however I’m fairly confident though that it’s not the DB requests that’s the bottleneck. The endpoint under test makes EF call to two separate tables to select all rows from each table. No joins, no filtering, just a select all. Both tables have around 3-4 columns (mainly guids) and maybe a total of few hundred rows.

Comment: When I test this endpoint on my localhost, it takes less than 20ms. I don’t see any load on the COU either.

Comment: The entities in front of those tables just have GUID fields, no navigation properties to other entities if these GUIDs are FKs? If Entities are passed back from a service call, the serializer will "touch" navigation properties causing them to be lazy-loaded. I recommend running a profiler against the DB to observe the queries being executed to eliminate the database as a bottleneck. Beyond that, per-request handling will degrade as the number of concurrent requests increase based on available cores & context switching.

Comment: Thanks for that. The guids in the tables are indeed FKs. I was under the impression that navigation properties are not lazy loaded if lazy loading is not explicitly switched on? Or is that not the case?

Comment: if this is EF6, lazy loading is on by default. A profiler will confirm whether lazy load is a factor or not. Projecting entities to a view model using `Select` to just get the FK fields eliminates any lazy load hits, navigation properties or no.

Comment: Thanks. Since I’ve never run a profiler, could you point me to any relevant docs that explain the process? Or perhaps edit the answer, either or.

Comment: If you are running SQL Server 2012 or higher one is available from Server Management Studio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017  I also use one called ExpressProfiler.  They are pretty straight forward. It helps to run against a database that isn't under heavy use to minimize the noise from unrelated queries.  Start it up, pause the profile run while you set up to get to the area of the app to test, then start the profiling and run your scenario in the app. It captures the SQL statements run.

Comment: Thanks. I’m using Postgres though so guessing it probably wont work. I’ll dig around a bit to see what’s out there for psql. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I believe PGAdmin has a profiler. I use PostgreSQL at home but don't recall having needed to profile against it. My projects had started out as SQL Server Express in the early days and moved across to Postgres. I've added an edit above to cover off what to look for when it comes to lazy load calls.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll have a go with PGAdmin.

Comment: I had a go with PGAdmin and struggled to make sense of the metrics I was receiving. Im looking at the 'Block I/O' graph and the number of 'hits' I'm seeing is a lot higher than the number of 'reads', which mostly always seems to be zero. I looked into how to clear cache and not sure I performed the right operations but after I executed a `DISCARD` query in `sql`, the read count went from 0 to 25 for the endpoint I'm testing. One strange thing that I did notice is in the Application Output in Visual Studio, the same SQL query seems to be executed twice.

Comment: For example, I'm seeing a `SELECT "ent"."Id", "ent"."Name" FROM "Subject" AS "ent" ORDER BY "ent"."Name"` printed twice each time the endpoint is called.

Comment: I'll see if I can check what profiling is available in PGAdmin once I get home this evening.  Does "Subject" reflect one of the tables you are querying? It doesn't look like a lazy load given the orderby. Lazy statements would be loading a record by PK or by FK.

Comment: Yes, “Subjects” is one of the tables being queried to retrieved all its rows.

Comment: A further observation I made today: 300 req/sec takes about the same time as a single req/sec but 350 req/sec makes response time more than 5 times longer. I can reproduce these results consistently.

Comment: I suspect then you may be reaching the threshold of request handling threads. If it's a virtual box, what happens if you increase the # of cores? What does the CPU load look like on the web server & SQL server? (I trust these are different servers, not running on the same physical/virtual instance?)

Comment: Correct. Different servers. The cpu usage on either one hasn’t risen above 10%.

Comment: Is there some predefined correlation between the number of threads Asp.Net can support (if that’s even a thing) and the # of cores?

Comment: Google-fu says Yes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/optimizing-iis-performance  It's not the kind of thing I'm normally tackling as I tend to set up load balancing quite early and then monitor the instance # and load over time. I generally favour several smaller instances over fewer big ones.  300 requests a second hitting a single web server with each request pinging a DB feels pretty heavy load for a single server. That said, 10% CPU isn't alarming in the slightest.