# Dapper query times greatly increase with concurrent operations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, dapper

I've built a .NET Core 3.1 API. The API does a lot of work, and the bulk of it is executing SQL Queries. Most of the API uses EF Core for its data access. However, for one particularly critical query, we've discovered that Dapper offered a significant performance advantage.

One test scenario we're testing involves calling the API with many requests per second. When tested In a linear fashion, the requests take a little less than a second. However, if we bombard the API with 10, 15, (up to 120) calls within a second, the query performance drops *dramatically*. As an example, linear queries take around 500ms. At 15 rapid calls (within a second or so), an average query time is 3600ms.

It's true that with "Wide" scenarios effective throughput **increases**. However, I can't see the database being the bottleneck here, and I wonder why requests take so much longer when many go on in a small period of time.

Another critical point to note is that if I alternate calls to our API hosted in an environment and my local box for instance, performance and throughput increases by around 30%. This lends credence to the theory that the DB itself isn't the primary issue. I've also found only [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57742882/why-does-response-time-go-up-when-the-number-of-concurrent-requests-per-second-t) being something close to what I'm asking, and it's focused on EF.

Dapper's used in an unobtrusive way. The EF Context has a typical lifetime (scoped) though I've experimented with singleton and transient. Here's what it looks like:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString)) //from EF properties
{
    using (var tx = await conn.BeginTransactionAsync(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
    {
        var details = conn.QueryAsync<OurObject>(
    @"SELECT columns
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2
    WHERE (someConditional = @paramValue)"
    , new
    {
        paramValue
    },tx);
        var res1 = Success((await details).ToList());
        return res1;
    }
}
```

It should be noted that we need to use this isolation level and transactions for a specific reason. We're reading from tables and then writing to them for each request. Dirty Reads are much less of a concern than locks.

We have detailed logging throughout the request lifecycle showing effectively that reads (and to a lesser extent, writes) take longer. The processing of data does not change and is very fast throughout each request.

Finally, I know this is a bigger question than many on S.O. I appreciate any information or things to try you can provide!

Comment: How are you running the app? If you're running in Visual Studio or something like the Test Server (in ASP.NET Core integration testing), you're dealing with thread-starvation. Those are single-threaded, so each request is queued and processed serially.

Comment: This is a good question - the behavior is identical when running locally or hitting a hosted API (though overall times are much higher in debug mode locally for instance). I'm able to get to the logs on the host and verify this.

Comment: I'll mention one more thing about the behavior. The console app doing load testing shows when requests go out and when they come back. In GENERAL, the API seems to have a psuedo-queue, in that it doesn't start returning responses until it's gotten most or all of the requests. As it continues to run it becomes more regular.

Answer (score 0):

> As an example, linear queries take around 500ms. At 15 rapid calls (within a second or so), an average query time is 3600ms.

...

> I can't see the database being the bottleneck here,

I can.

Assuming that 500ms is database server CPU time, 15 requests would require 7,500ms of CPU time. If the database server has 2 CPU cores it can process 4 queries/second.  15 queries would require 4.5sec.  But the server is quite capable of accepting all 15 requests at the same time (after 15 separate client sessions have been esatablished), and time-slicing the CPUs among the running requests.  So it may well be that all of the requests take an average of 3600ms.

For perspective 5ms is a "cheap" database query.  EG a single-row lookup by key will take well under 1ms of CPU time.  For a commonly-run query 500ms is expensive-enough to spend some time on analyzing the query plan and optimizing the execution.

Comment: Huge thank you for the reply! According to SSMS client statistics the query's time in SSMS is mostly network transfer. The one thing that leads me to believe the DB isn't the culprit (at least exclusively) is that if I simulate an ELB by alternatingly pinging my local and hosted versions of the API they both get lower query times than if I were to ping just one. Another way: the load on the DB is the same as it's handling 10 reqs/s, but each API is handling 5 reqs/s.